# Is a semi anechoic chamber with absorbers on the floor a fully anechoic chamber?

Tags: rf, measurement, radiation

I have a question about radiation measurements according to EN 300 328. According to the ETSI EN 300 328 V2.2.2 (2019-07) standard, measurements can be performed at one of the following three test sites:

- Free-field test site
- Semi-anechoic chamber
- Fully anechoic chamber

My question refers to the semi-anechoic room, which has a floor made of conductive metal. According to the standard, all measurements in the range from 30 MHz to 12.75 GHz can be performed in the semi-anechoic chamber. However, I often see test laboratories using removable absorbers for measurements in the range from 1 GHz to 12.75 GHz, which they place between the DUT and the antenna. Is a semi-anechoic room with absorbers on the ground plane still a semi-anechoic room or can it be considered a fully anechoic room in the range from 1 GHz to 12.75 GHz?